# Get Variable from .PHP File and echo it in a .JS File

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Hello Stackoverflow Users,

I hope you can help, basically say I have a PHP File with a variable, lets say
domain.com/forum/myname.php - In that myname.php file is:

```
$myname = "jake";
```

Now, I have a JS File at
domain.com/forum/js/template.js

How would I get this PHP Variable into the JS File?
I know once I have the PHP Variable I could do

```
var string = $myname;
```

and then use `string` wherever I want it to display, but the matter is how do I transfer it from PHP to the JS File?

I have seen other questions relating to this, but not one offers a clear explanation on how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set your variable $myname before calling external js file

Comment: use ajax and call from js and get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

index.php

```
$var = "hello world";
<script>
var phpVar = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
</script>

<script src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

in your jsfile.js :

```
alert(phpVar);
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to request your JS file through the PHP parser, and get PHP to output the correct content type `text/javascript`, then in your JS file you would do

```
var string = <?php echo $myname ?>;
```

or if you turn `short_open_tags` on then you can just do:

```
var string = <?= $myname ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `myname` variable as a global js variable. If you declare like this you can access any where in webpage files.

In **myname.php** file :

```
<script>
window.myname = <?php echo $myname;?> // declare as global variable
</script>
```

In **Js** File :

```
var myname = window.myname;
```

Comment: Hi Manibharathi, Thanks for your answer, however, when I try and show the var "myname" it comes up as undefined instead of showing the value

Comment: @user3615703 include the js file after declare the `window.myname`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have taken in the past is something like this:

in my js:

```
var myVal;

function init(val) { myVal = val; }
```

in my php:

```
<script>
....
var theVal = "<?=$phpVal?>";
init(theVal);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi mrpotocnik, Same Again, I tried this and when I try to show the var "theVal" - its coming up as undefined :(